# Correcting a hive script

Tags: hadoop, hive

Suppose I am writing any script for exa. creation of table as,

```
hive (test)>  create TABLE tlocal
           >     (id int,
           >      name string
           >      addr string);
```

> FAILED: ParseException line 4:5 mismatched input 'addr' expecting ) near 'string' in create table statement.

Here I forgot to add a comma after `name string`, so I got the error. I want to add the comma after `name string` and run again. But, like sql, hive does not allow you to correct only the wrong part of script - I have to rewrite the script again from beginning.

How can I do this?

Comment: So you're running directly in the hive client?  I'd suggest writing your query in a text editor and pasting it into the hive cli.  Or you can create and edit a sql file, and run it from the command line using `hive -f <your query file>`.

Answer (score 2):

As Andrew suggested you can write your query in a file and run it using

```
hive -f <your query file>
```

Alternatively you can use `Hue` which is open-source Web interface that supports Apache Hadoop SQL editors for Apache Hive.

Comment: Andrew and Piyush thank you very much for your help I will do as per your suggestions.